# How can I read the lines between the "start" and "end" flags from a file by using python

Tags: python, file

For example, the content of the file is:

```
this is the first line;
start
this is the second line;
this is the third line;
this is the forth line;
this is the fifth line;
end
this is the sixth line;
this is the seventh line;
```

"start" and "end" are flags,i want print the lines between these two flags. Result I want is:

```
this is the second line;
this is the third line;
this is the forth line;
this is the fifth line;
```

So, how can i process this file.

Comment: I can use file options to read the lines of file,but i don't know how to process the file with flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in Python just like you'd do it in any other language. The process would be:

- Initialize flag to False
- Open file
- Start reading lines; For each line read:

  - If flag is False:

    - Check if line == "start", if so set flag to True
  - If flag is True:

    - Check if line == "stop", if so stop reading
    - Else, print (or save) line
- Close file, etc.

Nothing Python-specific about it. Start by seeing how you do each of those things in Python (hint: it shouldn't be more lines than the lines of pseudocode above, really). If you have specific issues after you've tried, ask again.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
def read_sec(fle, start, end):
    from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile
    with open(fle) as f: 
        # drop lines until we reach start
        dp = dropwhile(lambda x: not x.rstrip() == start,f)
        next(dp) # skip start line
        # take lines until we hit our end line
        for line in takewhile(lambda x: x.rstrip() != end, dp):
            yield line.rstrip()


print(list(read_sec("test.txt","start","end")))
```

Output:

```
['this is the second line;', 'this is the third line;', 'this is the forth line;', 'this is the fifth line;']
```

`dropwhile` takes a condition as the first argument and an iterable as the second and will drop elements while your condition is True, i.e we have not reached the start line, then we call next on on the dropwhile object to skip the start line and use `takewhile` which takes similar argumnets to keep taking lines while we have not reached the end line i.e we have not reached `"end"`.

Or simply use a nested loop when you hit the start line and return when you reach the last line:

```
def read_sec(fle, start, end):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.rstrip() == start:
                for line in f:
                    if line.rstrip() == end:
                        return
                    yield line.rstrip()

print(list(read_sec("test.txt", "start", "end")))
```

Output:

```
['this is the second line;', 'this is the third line;', 'this is the forth line;', 'this is the fifth line;']
```

A file object returns its own iterator so when we reach the `start` line we start an inner loop over the file object which will start from the line after start,  we just yield each line until  we reach `end` where we just return to end the function.

Comment: I prefer the second solution, which is more compliant with The Zen Of Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: I am also confused about these code,but it is works very well.

Answer (score 1):

[KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)...

```
running = False
for line in file("data.txt"):
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "start":
        running = True
    elif line == "end":
        break
    elif running:
        print line
```

(note: python2-code-snippet)

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: You may return after reading "end", so to avoid unnecessary further readings

Comment: Why are you using `file` to open the file?

Comment: @Don You are right, returning / breaking out of the loop would be better, I'll update my answer @PadraicCunningham Cunningham: because `for line in file()` is the most pythonic way I can imagine to read a file line-by-line ;)

Comment: @PeterSchneider. with and open would be the pythonic way to open and read a file line by line, file does not exist at all in python3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - In that case, even the `print` statement should be modified.

Comment: @JRodDynamite, yes for python3 but it is easy wrap parens around what you are printing but you cannot use something that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small enough to fit in memory, you could use a simple regular expression as follows:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()
    print re.search(r'^start\n(.*?)^end\n', text, re.M|re.S).group(1)
```

This would print:

```
this is the second line;
this is the third line;
this is the forth line;
this is the fifth line;
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea if the file is big or its size is unknown

Comment: I agree, but the OP has not given an indication of size yet.

Comment: Ok, true; still, I think a straight-forward line by line read is even simpler to implement (more lines but doesn't require regex knowledge).

Comment: the file is about 10KB,it's not a big file,Thanks for your help